# HTML/CSS Header Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I made a Portfolio Website and have some issues with the header image. On the Smartphone and IPAD view, the full header image should not be shown - and that works. On my PC Monitor (24 inches) it works as well. But on my Laptop (15 inches) the header Image is isolated. You are only able to see like 40% of the image. (Screenshot with the Explanation is following)

[image: Header image]

1) This is the whole header image. The black background and number 3) is one single header image.

2) Just a regular Text on the header (unimportant)

```css
.hero_section {
  background-image: url(https://placekitten.com/1920/1080);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="hero_section bd-bottom">
  <div class="display-table">
    <div class="table-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Now I want the image to be fully shown as well on 15inch Monitors. I gave the image: `width: 100%;` so it should work normally.

There is the link to exact my image. Click  [this](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-c49546-1579636812.jpg.html)

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Rimble The image is only visable like 40%. I want it to be shown 100% (the whole image). And that on 15inch+ screens

Comment: What are the background image dimensions?

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 1920x1080 pixels

Comment: maybe you should create something with a preview (like an HTML\CSS\JS snippet) with the image and all so people can experience the problem themselves

Comment: @Thatkookooguy Thanks for the tipp - I´ll try it

Comment: I've made your code a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to help; you can use a "dummy image" host like, well, https://dummyimage.com/ to replace the URL of your background image with an appropriately sized image.

Comment: You might add what other css you are using that affects this section. Because the code itself looks ok, I tried it on JS Fiddle and it works with the image centered. Another conflicting code is probably sliding this picture out of the frame.

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 that´s the thing. The other classes are only formatations for the text. So there shouldn´t be any other css file or something else which is conflicting the code

Comment: @Kilian but how does this image disappear on mobile devices?

Comment: @renanAlmeida828 it simply gets cropped out of screen because of other screen widths

Comment: I added a new Link where you can get my exact picture.

Comment: Try using background-size: contain;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```css
.hero_section {
  background-image: url(https://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/c49546-1579636812.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
   .hero_section {
      background-image: none;
      background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="hero_section bd-bottom">
  <div class="display-table">
    <div class="table-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This should place your `background-image` always aligned to the right since your main subject (guy holding camera) is aligned that way. And when your screen is small (tablets or smaller) you remove the `background-image` and add a black background (adjust hex color as needed)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding something like this

```
.hero_section{
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/2648551) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!